# How to get nth record in a sql server table without changing the order?(sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

for example  i have data like this(sql server)

```
id    name
4      anu
3      lohi
1      pras
2      chand
```

i want  2nd record  in a table (means 3  lohi)
if i use row_number() function its changes the order  and i get  (2  chand)
i want  2nd record from table data

can anyonr please give me the query fro  above scenario

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as the *nth* row in a table.  And for a simple reason:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (technically multi-sets because they allow duplicates).

You can do what you want use `offset`/`fetch`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by id desc
offset 1 fetch first 1 row only;
```

This assumes that the descending ordering on `id` is what you want, based on your example data.

You can also do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 2;
```

I should note that that SQL Server allows you to assign `row_number()` without having an effective sort using something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 2;
```

However, this returns an *arbitrary* row.  There is no guarantee it returns the same row each time it runs, nor that the row is "second" in any meaningful use of the term.

Comment: Thank u gordon ,can u please explain this point "SQL tables represent unordered sets (technically multi-sets because they allow duplicates)."

Comment: @srini . . . What needs to be explained?  There is no ordering to SQL tables, so there is no "second" row . . . or "first" row . . . or "last" row.